# How to define a users group using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, users, group

I am having hard time adding a user to a group in script.

For example, i have a script that asks user to answer several questions, and if answers are correct, that user should be added to a certain group.

So I probably need a way to somehow identify which user is answering questions (there are multiple users) and based on his answers add him/her to a group.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange Unix&Linux. Please take the time to read the [tour]. Do you have some example of what you did ? on this site we expect some proof of work please [edit] your question to add some more context to it.

Answer (score 1):

I also created a simple script.
Below script is creating a new user on the system.
I'm very glad if you can use it as a reference.
Set the group name to VALIDGROUPS variable beforehand and
select it at the time of execution.

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2
 3  VALIDGROUPS="GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3"
 4
 5  printf "Add your account on this system\n\n"
 6  printf "Enter your name here, No space allowed for your user name : "
 7  read USERNAME
 8
 9  printf "Valid user groups are $VALIDGROUPS Choose select one: "
10  read USERGROUP
11
12  grep $USERGROUP /etc/group 2>&1>/dev/null
13  if [ $? != 0 ]
14  then
15      printf "Group Name you entered $USERGROUP is not valid\n"
16      printf "Creating Abort!\n"
17      exit 1
18  else
19      useradd -g $USERGROUP -d /home/$USERNAME -s /bin/bash -m $USERNAME
20      passwd $USERNAME
21  fi
22
23  id $USERNAME
24
25  printf "done!\n"
26
27  exit 0
```

Comment: The line numbers you've added make it impossible for anyone to copy'n'paste your script. Please could I suggest you remove them.

Comment: The thing is that I do not need to create users. All users are already created.

Comment: what is the point of doing ```/etc/group 2>&1>/dev/null```in line 12? Does ```>/dev/null``` adds something I am missing?

Comment: @RicarHincapie it's a no-op except that the match result (yes/no) is used on the subsequent line. The two lines could have been written `if grep -F "$USERGROUP" >/dev/null 2>&1` or even `if grep -qF "$USERGROUP"`. Unfortunately in both cases a `USERGROUP=fred` would match to `freddie` so it's a poor condition check anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line in your script to find out who is executing the script using

```
user=$(whoami)
echo $user
```

If the script needs to be run with sudo, `whoami` will always give root as user , so you need to use `$SUDO_USER` variable

```
user=$SUDO_USER
echo $user
```

If the user uses, `su -` and then executes the script, then the above solutions will not work, use `who am i`

```
user=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
echo $user
```

Comment: Yes you are right, had not tried that ,will add that to the answer @roima thanks